# Excel 2007 Minimize the Ribbon programatically but Not the menu bar

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

In excel 2007, we can just right click on ribbon and select 'Minimize the ribbon' & minimize it.

I have tried

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("show.toolbar(\"ribbon\",false)");
```

which hides the whole ribbonbut I do not wish to hide whole ribbon.

I have even tried

```
 Application.SendKeys("^{F1}", true);
```

but it's not reliable as sometimes it doesn't work properly.

[image]

Is there any way to do it using C# VSTO code ?

I read a lot about `toggleribbon()` function but couldn't find way to use it.

**EDIT:**
There is way you can actually find if the ribbon is already minimized. i used

```
    Office.CommandBars cbs = null;
    cbs = Application.CommandBars;
    foreach (Office.CommandBar cb in cbs)
    {
       if (cb.Name == "Ribbon")
       {

         if (cb.Height > 90)
         {
            this.Application.ActiveWindow.Activate(); 
            //to get focus on current workbook so that sendkeys will work
            Application.SendKeys("^{F1}", true);
          }

        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 Great question, if it's any help the equivalent in MS Access is `DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SendKeys` <kbd>CTRL+F1</kbd> works, but it seems to be a timing issue with its execution. The real issue is that you don't know when the Ribbon is actually loaded in Excel to trigger the behavior.

This code seemed to work reliably for me, but it truly depends on how quickly your add-ins load. You can also utilize `Thread.Sleep()` if needed.

```cs
 private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
       //Thread.Sleep(1000); // optional
       Application.SendKeys("^{F1}");
   }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
 }
```

[See related MSDN forum post regarding Ribbon load timing](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/baa9a81d-aad3-4af5-9d0a-f945c26ffa18/).

Comment: You can find out if the ribbon is minimized or not using height property. Iterate on commandbars and check for `name=="Ribbon"` I have added a code to check if ribbon is minimized or maximized.