# c# Excel - Display ribbon on exit

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm using VSTO to design an application with an Excel interface. I want to hide the ribbon on startup (shouldn't be needed in the application) and re-display it on exit (if the user had it originally displayed), to avoid irritating people who use the application and want a ribbon the next time they open Excel.

I can hide the ribbon using essentially the following code in `ThisWorkbook_Startup` (from this question [Excel 2007 Minimize the Ribbon programatically but Not the menu bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514660/excel-2007-minimize-the-ribbon-programatically-but-not-the-menu-bar)):

```
        Office.CommandBars cbs = null;
        cbs = Application.CommandBars;

        foreach (Office.CommandBar commandBar in cbs)
        {
            if (commandBar.Name == "Ribbon")
            {
                this.Application.ActiveWindow.Activate();
                Application.SendKeys("^{F1}", true);
            }
        }
```

However, the same code or similar variations from the previously referenced question do not seem to work when placed in either the `ThisWorkbook_Shutdown` or `ThisWorkbook_BeforeClose` methods. The code is hit but never seems to execute - the ribbon is never restored.

Is there another way to restore the ribbon on exit?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: +1 - I tried to work around this and looked around and could not find anything that worked

Comment: Have you been able to solve this yet? I'd be interested in the solution

Comment: No I haven't unfortunately, I'll post something if I do though.